# array with objects transformation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with objects smth like this:

```
arr = [
  {name: 'Igor', id: 1,....},
  {name: 'Anton', id: 1,.... },
  {name: 'Igor', id: 2,.... },
  {name: 'Peter', id: 2,.... },
  {name: 'Igor', id: 2,.... }
]
```

I need to get new array like:

```
arrId = [
  { id: 1, names: 'Igor, Anton' },
  { id: 2, names: 'Igor, Peter' }
]
```

can't think of good solution

Comment: you can use _reduce_

Comment: Can you tell the exact difference between these two arrays?

Comment: @void, names groupped by id

Comment: can you explain what rules you use to generate new arrays?

Comment: I'm assuming `{ id: 1, names: 'Igor, Peter' }` should be `{ id: 2, names: 'Igor, Peter' }`, otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: @Andy yeah, sorry about that, my mistake

Comment: @Grundy well my thought are first: to sort objects in arr by id, then: create new array and add items to it something like this: while(arr.id==i) push new items to new array and combine names. But if I do it like this I'll get not what I want :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example I use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
function rearrange(arr) {

  // use `reduce` to build an object using the ids as keys
  // this allows us to place all the names with the same id together
  // note we pass in an empty object to act as our initial p argument.
  var out = arr.reduce(function (p, c) {
    var key = c.id, name = c.name;

    // if the key doesn't exist create it and set its value
    // to an empty array
    p[key] = p[key] || [];

    // add the name to the array if it doesn't already exist
    if (p[key].indexOf(name) === -1) p[key].push(name);
    return p;
  }, {});

  // use `map` to return an array of objects
  return Object.keys(out).map(function (el) {

    // make sure we use an integer for the id, and
    // join the array to get the appropriate output
    return { id: +el, names: out[el].join(', ') };
  });

}

rearrange(arr);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/cfrmfbdy/1/)

OUTPUT

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "names": "Igor, Anton"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "names": "Igor, Peter"
  }
]
```

Comment: especially* sorry for my English

Comment: @IgorKim, your English is fine. Don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use *reduce* function

```js
arr = [
  {name: 'Igor', id: 1},
  {name: 'Anton', id: 1 },
  {name: 'Igor', id: 2 },
  {name: 'Peter', id: 2 },
  {name: 'Igor', id: 2 }
]

//first group needed fields from items by id
var result = arr.reduce(function(acc,cur){
  if(!acc.map[cur.id]) {
    acc.map[cur.id] = {id:cur.id, names:{}};
    acc.result.push(acc.map[cur.id]);
    }
  acc.map[cur.id].names[cur.name]=true;
  return acc;
},{map:{},result:[]})
//do addtional transfrom from map object with names, to string separated by comma
.result.map(function(el){
  return {id:el.id, names: Object.keys(el.names).join(', ')};
});
console.log(result);
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result,null, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrId = [];
var arrKey = {};
for( var counter = 0; counter < arr.length; counter++)
{ 
  var arrObj = arr[ counter ];
  if ( !arrKey[  arrObj[ "id" ] ] )
  {
    arrKey[  arrObj[ "id" ] ] = [];
  }
  arrKey[  arrObj[ "id" ] ].push( arrObj[ "name" ] );
}
for ( var id in arrKey )
{
  arrId.push( [ "id": id, names : arrKey[ id ].join( "," ) ] );
}
console.log(arrId );
```